# 端末のディスプレイサイズに応じてボタンの位置を変えたい(Swift)

Tags: swift, ios

StoryBoard上に乗せたボタンの位置を、
アプリ実行端末のディスプレイサイズに応じて変えたいと考えています。

位置を変えるには
button_Save.frame.origin.y += 100
のように設定すると良いと考えていたのですが変わりませんでした。
どのように設定する必要があるでしょうか。
このボタンはアウトレット接続しており、制約などは特に設定していません。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    displaySize = self.view.frame.size
    if displaySize.height == 480 { //4/4S
         print("this is iPhone4/4s")
         //Do Nothing. This is base size
    }
    else if displaySize.height == 568{ //5/5S
        //保存ボタンを下にずらす
        print("this is iPhone5/5s")
        button_Save.frame.origin.y += 100
    }
(以下略)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> アプリ実行端末のディスプレイサイズに応じて変えたいと考えています。

ディスプレイサイズに応じて変えたいということですが、iOS の場合 iOS 8 以降サイズクラスという仕組みが導入されました。それとオートレイアウトを使いスクリーンサイズに応じたインターフェースを簡単に作ることができます。

スクリーンサイズに応じてボタン(UIButton)の配置を変える例を説明します。

ボタンを Object Library からドラッグ＆ドロップし配置します。
[図1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwyKt.png)

先程配置したボタンにコンストレイントを設定します。
[図2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNCJi.png)

サイズクラスを幅を Any、高さを Compact に変更します。
[図3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRe35.png)

このサイズクラスでボタンを配置したい場所へとボタンを移動させ再配置します。
[図4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmGNV.png)

ボタンのコンストレイントを再設定します。まずボタンの上にマウスカーソルを持って行き、そこからコントロールキーを押しながらドラッグすると青い線を引いてこれます。この青い線をドラッグして関連付けるターゲットが view になるようにしマウスを離します。
[図5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP7NN.png)

メニュが出てくるので trailing space のコンストレイントを選択します。
[図6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP4d0.png)

次にコンフリクトを起こすコンストレイントを削除します。図7で指し示している leading space のコンストレイントを選択しデリートキーを押して削除します。
[図7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7IvE.png)

以上でスクリーンサイズに応じてボタンの位置が変わるようにする設定は終わりました。
実行してボタンの位置が変わるか見てみましょう。⌘Rで実行します。

ポートレイトでは中央左端にボタンが配置されています。
[図8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpqCU.png)

ランドスケープに切り替えると中央右端にボタンが配置されます。
[図9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlFBk.png)

このようにサイズクラスとオートレイアウトを使うとスクリーンサイズに合わせたインターフェースを簡単に作ることができます。

またこの例ではあるサイズクラスでコンストレイントの追加と削除を行ったように、サイズクラスでは次の点をサイズクラスごとに変更しそれぞれのスクリーンサイズに合わせてインターフェースを変化させることができます。
* ビューの大きさと位置の変更
* ビューの追加と削除
* コンストレイントの変更と追加と削除
* ラベル、テキストフィールド、テキストビュー、ボタンのフォントの変更

次の文献に詳しく解説されているので参考にしてください。
[Adaptive User Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/)
[Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit - WWDC 2014](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/216/)
[Size Classes Design Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html)

Comment: サイズクラスとコンストレイントの関係性について（完全ではありませんが）理解が深まりました。そして、同サイズクラス内での端末ごとの調整は大変そうだと感じました。詳しくは返答にまとめさせて頂きました。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決したかもしれません。
今までoverride func viewDidLoad()で処理を行おうとしていたのですが、これをoverride func viewDidLayoutSubviews()を作成して、その中で行うとボタンの位置が変更できました。

表示する文字列などはviewDidLoad()で変更できるのですが、レイアウト関連は
viewDidLayoutSubviews()じゃないと変更できないようですね。

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    displaySize = self.view.frame.size
    if displaySize.height == 480 { //4/4S
         print("this is iPhone4/4s")
         //Do Nothing. This is base size
    }
    else if displaySize.height == 568{ //5/5S
        //保存ボタンを下にずらす
        print("this is iPhone5/5s")
        button_Save.frame.origin.y += 100
    }
(以下略)
}
```

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews()を使用して問題が発生中です。UISegmentedControlの位置を変えた後にシミュレータ上でUISegmentedControlの切り替えをポチると、StoryBoardで設定した初期位置へセグが移動してしまう問題です。本件に関しては調査中ですが、また別の質問として立てさせて頂くかもしれません、

Comment: AutoLayoutを有効にしている場合、制約を設定しなかった場合は「暗黙の制約」が設定されます。`viewDidLayoutSubviews()`の前でタイミングで`frame`を操作しても表示が変わらないのはそのためです。また、`viewDidLayoutSubviews()`の後で`frame`を操作した場合も制約が再度有効になった場合は元の位置に戻ります。

Comment: アプリのライフサイクルとどのタイミングでメソッドがコールされるか少し分かってきました。また、AutoLayoutによる設定とviewDidLayoutSubviews()の両方を同時に使用すること自体、あまり宜しくないようですね。調べていると幾つかの資料にもそのような記述がございました。

Answer (score 0):

Yuu Qさん、大変丁寧な回答をありがとうございます。
サイズクラスに応じてコンストレイントを設定出来ることは分かりました。
しかし、同一サイズクラス内で端末毎となると、コンストレイントを色々と駆使する必要がありそうで、かなりコツが必要そうだと改めて感じております。（※理由は後述します）

一旦、現状を整理してお話させて頂くと以下の通りとなります。

今回私はiPhone4/4S/5/5S/6/6S/6Plus向けのアプリで縦向きのアプリを作ろうとしています。サイズクラスで言うところのW:C,H:Rです。
このサイズクラスで各端末ごとに表示を整えたく、viewDidLayoutSubviews()内のコーディングでレイアウトを整えることにより、一応見た目だけは理想に近づきつつあります。（画像の②。コーディング前は一番右の画像の状態。）
ただ、問題も幾つか出てきています。
１：コードが冗長になった
２：UISegmen‌​tedControlで、タップするとコントローラが②の画像の位置から、一番右の画像の位置へ移動する現象が起きたので対応が必要

そのため、やはり出来るだけStoryBoardから設定するように出来ないかと考えています。
調べてみたところ、
・UI Viewを複数乗せて画面サイズに応じて比率を制約で指定する（参考リンク１）
・隙間の制約のアウトレットを追加して端末ごとに比率を制約で指定する（参考リンク２）
・ダミーのUIViewをコントローラの間に差し込んであげて、端末ごとに隙間の比率を制約で指定する
といった方法を知りました。
（※みんな苦労しているなぁと感じています。ここが前述の「コツが必要そう」と感じた部分です。）

結論として
・サイズクラスごとでは、コンストレイントの指定がStoryBoard上から比較的手軽に指定出来る
・同一サイズクラスにおいては、理想に近づけるためには『コンストレイントを駆使して頑張る』
という考えに至っております。

私自身、まだサイズクラスやオートレイアウト、コンストレイントを熟知していないため、もし
「同じサイズクラスでももっと簡単に調整できるぞ」という方法がございましたら是非ご教授願います。

////以下、参考リンク及びイメージ画像////

※アクセスは頭にhを付ける
[リンク１：AutoLayoutでViewのサイズやUIレイアウトをパーセント指定する方法]
ttp://qiita.com/emadurandal/items/04c11db5eb1117eabe1e
[リンク２：【Swift】Auto Layoutで特定のデバイス・画面サイズの時だけ制約を変更する方法]
ttp://egg-is-world.com/2014/12/25/auto-layout-device/

[image: UIのイメージ図]

Answer (score 0):

AutoLayoutについてまだ[こちら](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutoLayoutGuide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html)をご覧になっていないのであれば、是非ご一読ください。

私としてはグループ化とスタックビューの使用をお勧めしておきます。

(1) 横に並んだ一まとまりのUI部品をグループ化する

グループにまとめたい要素を全て選択した状態で、XcodeのメニューからEditor>Embed In>Viewを選ぶと、選択された要素全てを含む新しいUIViewがView階層に追加されます。あなたの回答にあるような画面ですと、5〜6グループにまとめるのが適当でしょうか。

(2) 上記のグループをさらにスタックビューで囲む

上の(1)で作った5〜6個のグループの代表であるUIViewを全部選択して、Editor>Embed In>Stack Viewで、それらのグループを子要素に持つUIStackViewを作成します。

(3) スタックビューの属性を設定する

細かいところの微調整は後にして、AxisをVertical, DistributionをEqual Spacingに設定してください。これにより、各グループの隙間が同じ幅になるようにレイアウトされます。

(4) グループ内で適切な制約を設定する

画面全体にあれこれ制約を張り巡らせるのは結構大変ですが、ある程度絞り込んだグループの中での制約であれば、比較的簡単に設定できるはずです。

言葉だけですと少しわかりにくいですが、ご自身で少し簡略化したサンプルを作って試しながら再度読み直していただけるとわかりやすくなると思います。
　スタックビューはiOS9以降の機能なので、それ以前のバージョンもサポートする必要がある場合には使えませんが、画面全体に多数のUI要素がある場合にグループ化して管理すると言うのは、スタックビューが使えない場合でも有効な手段です。是非お試しください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ちょうど、スタックビューを検証し始めた頃でした。触り始めたばかりで多数のワーニングメッセージが暴れていますが、やりたいことが実現できそうな予感がしております

Comment: @Alto さん、既存のstoryboardがあるのならグループ化した方が簡単かと思い上記の方法をご説明しましたが、既存の設定が絡んだウォーニングが出ているのであれば、まっさらなViewControllerを用意して全体を覆うようにVertical Stack Viewを貼り付ける→グループとなるUIViewをその子Viewとなるように貼り付ける→(この時点でスタックビューとしてのレイアウトを十分調整する、慣れないうちは各グループの高さは固定値の制約にするのがオススメ)→各グループにUI部品を貼り付けていき、グループごとにグループ内で完結するように制約を設定していく、といった形の方が簡単かもしれません。